# If [post] null show error .Net Core repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-core, null, asp.net-core-mvc, http-post, repository-pattern

What is the best way to display Title == null?
I am doing with .Net Core and using the Repository Pattern, I cannot show the error table when the value of Title is null for my Article. What do I need to do for this method?
I have tried to use code like this but it still fails, maybe I need to work with Repository?

**View**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12">
    <div class="card card-small mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form asp-action="SubmitArticle" id="SubmitForm" class="add-new-post">
                <input asp-for="Article.Author" hidden class="form-control" readonly value="@Model.UserFullName"/>
                <partial name="_StatusMessage" model="@ViewData["Message"]"/>
                <input asp-for="Article.Title" class="form-control form-control-lg mb-3" type="text" placeholder="Your Post Title">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <label asp-for="Article.FacultyId" class="col-form-label"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <select asp-for="@Model.Article.FacultyId" asp-items="@Model.Faculties.Select(f => new SelectListItem() {Text = f.FacultyName.ToString(), Value = f.Id.ToString()})" class="form-control"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I try but how can show error?

Comment: You can see my answer.

Comment: You can also see the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: I revised the code, as you can see above, it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you share your view?

Comment: I have shared it, please help me

Comment: Hi @HuyNguyen,Does this solution help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Repository like below:

```
public ArticleFacultyViewModel SubmitArticle(ArticleFacultyViewModel articleFacultyViewModel)
    {
        var doesArticleExists = _dbContext.Articles.Include(a => a.Faculty)
                                                    .Where(a => a.Title == articleFacultyViewModel.Article.Title && a.Faculty.Id == articleFacultyViewModel.Article.FacultyId);

            if (articleFacultyViewModel.Article.Title == null)
            {
               return articleFacultyViewModel;
            }
            else
            {
            _dbContext.Articles.Add(articleFacultyViewModel.Article);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return null;
            }
            
        var model = new ArticleFacultyViewModel()
        {
            Article = articleFacultyViewModel.Article,
            Faculties = _dbContext.Faculties.ToList(),
            StatusMessage = "Error: Article already exists in " + _dbContext.Faculties.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == articleFacultyViewModel.Article.FacultyId).FacultyName.ToString()
        };

        return model;
    }
```

Then in your method:

```
 public IActionResult SubmitArticle(ArticleFacultyViewModel articleFacultyViewModel)
{   
    var articleSubmit = _studentRepository.SubmitArticle(articleFacultyViewModel);
    
     if (articleSubmit == articleFacultyViewModel)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Article.Title", "Please Enter Your Title");
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (articleSubmit == null)
            {

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
         ViewData["Message"] = articleSubmit.StatusMessage;
        }
        return View(articleSubmit);
}
```

In your view:

```
 <input asp-for="Article.Title" class="form-control form-control-lg mb-3" type="text" placeholder="Your Post Title">
 <span asp-validation-for="Article.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Comment: Hi @HuyNguyen,recheck the view I updated.

Comment: Would you like to help me through teamview?

Comment: Probably not, since this is a group exercise. I can't push it publicly

Comment: Hi @HuyNguyen,When your Title is null, click Submit. [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBX6j.png)

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Title', table 'Megatron.dbo.Articles'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Delete `[Required(ErrorMessage = ""Please Enter Your Title"")]`

Comment: In this case, it is not needed

Comment: Do you think you should work in Repository instead of Controller?

Comment: I deleted first

Comment: Always Here: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Title', table 'Megatron.dbo.Articles'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated

Comment: This code `if(articleFacultyViewModel.Article.Title == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Article.Title", "Please Enter Your Title");
        }` should in your Repository,not controller

Comment: But there is a problem with what to use instead of `ModelState.AddModelError`

Comment: Yes, if I could use it I probably wouldn't have asked everyone here.

Comment: You can  directly return a model, and then judge in your method, if you return the model, then use `ModelState.AddModelError`

Comment: I have my Repository show on post. It is the first paragraph

Comment: Hi @HuyNguyen,I think I find the solution,you can check it.

Comment: Yes @HuyNguyen,you can check my answer.

Comment: In Method `if (model == null)` what is model

Comment: Hi @HuyNguyen,Sorry, typing error,it's `articleSubmit `

Comment: I tried the change but it doesn't work either

Comment: It's still the same error message as before

Comment: Hi @HuyNguyen,the real reson of your issue is you shouldn't use `if (doesArticleExists.Any())`

Comment: Just delete it,like my updated `Repository`.

Comment: Because your `doesArticleExists` is a `article` type, The receiving type is `ViewModel`,They cannot judge together.

Comment: I made your copy, but it's really ineffective

Comment: Error: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)